# Do I need to close DirectoryReader while using Lucene Near real-time indexing feature

Tags: java, indexing, solr, lucene

Am using Lucence 4.7.2 and am new to it. I tried looking into the lucene source code, but was not able to find the information. The reason for using near real-time is, while searching the index should be visible withing 1 minute of creation.

I have created the following trying to implement/use lucene NRT (near real-time) feature.

```
//Code to initialize IndexWriter and Near real-time IndexReader. 
//(DirectoryReader is used as IndexReader(IndexWriter, boolean) contructor is deprecated.
directory = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/Users/arun/lucene-home/"));
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47, analyzer);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);

//NOTE 1
DirectoryReader directoryReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, true);
```

As per documentation of  [DirectoryReader openIfChanged(DirectoryReader oldReader, IndexWriter writer, boolean applyAllDeletes)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#openIfChanged%28org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter,%20boolean%29)

Everytime before performing a search, I create IndexSearcher as below

```
DirectoryReader newDirectoryReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(directoryReader , indexWriter, true);
IndexSearcher nrtIndexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(newDirectoryreader);
```

**Question:**

Will the original DirectoryReader "directoryReader " stated in the above code with comment "NOTE 1" be closed by lucene itself? I mean the DirectoryReader implementation or the class that used in it?

If not, how do I track if the IndexSearcher that was created from the DirectoryReader is still being referenced before closing DirectoryReader.

Note: I will not be able to use Solr, Please excuse me.

Comment: what do you mean closed by lucene itself? you are responsible for closing the `IndexReader`. On the other hand, the `IndexSearcher` has no `close` method. As a side note.... have a look at the `SearcherManager` class and follow this example on how to use it : http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/

Comment: I don't think SearchManager is recommended for near real-time scenario. Refer to answer by 'mindas' and the comments below it. Feel free to correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: `Searchermanager` has all the methods needed to make your search NRT : `isSearcherCurrent` and `refreshIfNeeded` . Just have a look at the code samples out there

Answer (score 2):

Each `IndexReader` has to be closed after being used, otherwise you will end up with ["Too many open files"](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_am_I_getting_an_IOException_that_says_.22Too_many_open_files.22.3F) exception.

If you are using `openIfChanged`, you can check reference equality to see if the reader is different or not:

```
DirectoryReader oldReader = directoryReader;
DirectoryReader newReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(directoryReader);
if ((newReader != null) & (oldReader != newReader)) {
   directoryReader = newReader;
   oldReader.close();
   // need to close the old one
} else {
   // nothing to do
}
```

Note: if you are using this in a multi-threaded environment, there's a chance the old reader is still in use - so if you close it too early, searches using old reader (searcher, created using this reader) will fail. The cure for this is `NRTManager` and/or `SearcherManager`.

Comment: As you said, I cannot close Reader without checking whether its being referred. Do you have any code snippet on using NRTManager.

Comment: Just browse around, http://puneetkhanal.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/real-time-search-in-lucene-aka.html is an example I found via Google in less time it took me to type this.

Comment: I was not able to find NRTManager class in lucence-core. Looking into the changes, I found that it has been replaced with org.apache.lucene.search.ControlledRealTimeReopenThread<T>. 

Reference 1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4967.
Reference 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993960/lucene-4-4-0-new-controlledrealtimereopenthread-sample-usage.

Comment: @mindas I think your solution is wrong as "openIfChanged" returns null if the reader has not changed. Ref: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_2/core/index.html

Comment: @Ivan ok, and you end up comparing `null` and non-null, resulting false (else branch). What's wrong with that?

Comment: @mindas In your example you are comparing for inequality so with `null` and non-null it results `true` and the new value for "directoryReader" will be `null`.

Comment: @Ivan yes, you are absolutely correct! Fixed the snippet, thanks for noticing.